# Invalid username error while using Spotify API using python

Tags: python, spotify

I used the below python program to generate token using Spotify API

```
import requests

CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'

AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'

# POST
auth_response = requests.post(AUTH_URL, {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
})

# convert the response to JSON
auth_response_data = auth_response.json()

# save the access token
access_token = auth_response_data['access_token']

print("token is ")
print(access_token)
```

This prints the token

Now i am trying to curl and get current playing track using this token using this command

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing?market=ES" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxGenrated Tokenxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

But i am getting Invalid username error, how to fix this

```
{
  "error" : {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Invalid username"
  }
}
```

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych OP isn't using Spotipy, they are trying to retrieve the data manually using the requests library, but it might be easier to solve this problem using Spotipy anyways

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych i didnt use the spotify library